# Being Madrid my hometown / Being my hometown Madrid

Tags: word-order

Being **Madrid my hometown**, I'm used to living surrounded by tourists.

Being **my hometown Madrid**, I'm used to living surrounded by tourists.

Which of the sentences, if either, sounds more natural?

Comment: Neither. Limiting to those 4 words, it's "Madrid being my hometown". More natural would be, "Being/seeing that Madrid is my hometown..."

Comment: [Consider the English Language Learners site.](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 8):

Neither really sounds natural. This should be phrased as "My hometown being Madrid, I'm used to living surrounded by tourists."

Comment: Or _Madrid being my hometown_, ...

Comment: *Being that Madrid is my hometown* is frowned upon in writing, but something I hear from even educated people, being as how Washington is full of people who want to sound smarter than they are.

Answer (score 3):

Madrid being my hometown, I'm used to living surrounded by tourists.